# Set custom typeface for eche RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-fonts

I use `RecyclerView` and `CardView` and I want to add a custom font to the `TextView` within one of the `RecyclerView` items.

1. Where in my adapter should I set the font?
2. Also how exactly do I set the font?

For example: set *Durwent.ttf* in `item 1` and "Fenwick.ttf" in `item 2`.

This is my `adapter.java`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(List<RecyclerItem> listItems, Context mContext) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
//                if (position == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, listItems.get(position).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

/*
                }
                if (position == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Android",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
*/

            }
        });
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final RecyclerItem itemList = listItems.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(itemList.getTitle());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(itemList.getDescription());
        holder.txtOptionDigit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Display option menu
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.txtOptionDigit);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.mnu_item_save:
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved " + listItems.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case R.id.mnu_item_delete:
                                //Delete item
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted " + listItems.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                listItems.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView txtTitle;
        public TextView txtDescription;
        public TextView txtOptionDigit;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            txtOptionDigit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is in the onBindViewHolder, also the addActionListeners should be there too, in your code you are binding at onCreate

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Docs about Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

Set font-family as describe in Android doc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
<font
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
</font-family>
```

Apply font-family to your TextView,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

Create recycler view which have two different items, For eg,
FontViewHolder (include font enabled TextView in this CardView) & NormalViewHolder and based on conditions, you can use particular ViewHolder. For eg,

```
public class YourAdapater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private static final int FONT_ITEM_TYPE = 0x01;
  private static final int DEFAULT_ITEM_TYPE = 0x02;

  private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;

  public YourAdapater(List<RecyclerItem> listItems) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
      return FONT_ITEM_TYPE; // constant say 0x01
    }
    return DEFAULT_ITEM_TYPE; // constant say 0x02
  }

  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    if (viewType == FONT_ITEM_TYPE) {
      // inflate and return FontViewHolder
      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_font, parent, false);
      return new FontViewHolder(view);
    } else {
      // inflate and return NormalViewHolder
      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_normal, parent, false);
      return new NormalViewHolder(view);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
      FontViewHolder vh = (FontViewHolder) holder;
      vh.bind(listItems.get(position));
    } else {
      NormalViewHolder vh = (NormalViewHolder) holder;
      vh.bind(listItems.get(position));
    }
  }

  public static class NormalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtTitle;
    public TextView txtDescription;
    public TextView txtOptionDigit;

    private RecyclerItem item;

    public NormalViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
      txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
      txtOptionDigit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);

      itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // click action on item
          if (item != null) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
    }

    public void bind(RecyclerItem item) {
      this.item = item;
      // do data binding
      txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
      txtDescription.setText(item.getDescription());
    }
  }

  public static class FontViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public FontViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // click action on item
        }
      });
    }

    public void bind(RecyclerItem data) {
      // do data binding
    }
  }
}
```

In this way, you can re-use your font-family in future and extend functionality, based on your context.

Comment: Updated and added some tips, for eg, onclick event

Comment: where add font code i want change one textview for eche recyclerView item

Comment: In your layout file, for eg, recycler_item_font.xml, you can add TextView which have font-family.

Comment: yes i know .. but i have one textview id for all item :(

Comment: Do you want to add font for one Item or some items? (the above adapter work for such scenario). It is fine if the textview id is same, recycler view will do the magic, works on items and try to re-use items.

Comment: for one Item but i have same id .. like position == 0 have textview id "tv" in title set font and position == 1 have textview id "tv" set other font

Comment: Over here, position == 0, will use FontViewHolder, which use recycler_item_font.xml layout file, and other positions, will use NormalViewHolder with recycler_item_font.xml layout file. So all good, it should work, you can give try.

Comment: Remember to upvote and accept answer my friend, thanks.

Comment: @M.bala7 I remember, you accepted this answer, but it is not there any more, Remember to upvote and accept answer my friend.

Answer (score -1):

@M.bala7 please with below step for set different font on different position

1- first create assets folder 
   Right click on app > new > folder > assest folder >select main > click ok

[image]
2- put font in assets folder .

[image]
then in code

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

   Typeface font1= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Durwent.ttf");
 Typeface font2= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Fenwick.ttf");
}

 // you can apply font position wise 

  if (position == 0) {
        //set font 1 
         textView.setTypeface(font1);
    } 
 if (position == 1){
       //set font 2 
         textView.setTypeface(font2);
    }

--------------or-----------------

   if (position % 2 == 0) {
        //set font 1 
         textView.setTypeface(font1);
    } else {
       //set font 2 
         textView.setTypeface(font2);
    }
 }
```

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` is called each time a view is added, doing it like this will cause UI lag.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder)holder;
    Current current = currentList.get(position);
    myHolder.textDescription.setText(current.getDescription());
    myHolder.textTitle.setText(current.getTitle());
    myHolder.textSource.setText(current.getRelease_date());
    myHolder.textType.setText(current.getContent_type());


    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "myFirstFont.ttf");
    Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "mySecondFont.ttf");
   if(position % 2 ==0 )
   {
       myHolder.textDescription.setTypeface(font1);

   }else
       myHolder.textDescription.setTypeface(font2);


}
```

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` is called each time a view is added, this will cause lag.